# How do I install OpenSSH on Ubuntu 12.10 without apt-get?

Tags: openssh, apt-get, ubuntu-12.10

I need to use Ubuntu 12.10 and want to install OpenSSH on it. Since this is a deprecated version of Ubuntu I cannot use apt-get to attain the wanted package, so how should I move forth to be able to install it?

Comment: Why do you want to use Ubuntu 12.10? There may be a workaround for whatever problem it is which is making you want to use such an old Ubuntu release.

Comment: Unfortunately no. My company has outsourced some drivers that uses the 12.10 versions of quite a few modules. We can of course port the drivers ourselves, but that takes time. Using 12.10 is a bit easier in this case ;)

Comment: So your company uses some drivers which depend on some Ubuntu 12.10 kernel modules?  If I may ask, what are the drivers for?

Comment: No you cannot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to an old release of Ubuntu, you need to make changes in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.  Change its content with this:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

From then on, you should be able to do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install it from a DVD, you can use apt-get to install packages which are available on this DVD.

Anyway, here is what you can do :

Download the dvd image : http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/

Became root : "sudo bash"

Mount it :

```
mount image.iso /cdrom -o loop
```

Find your package :

```
find /cdrom -name 'openssh*.deb'
```

Install it :

```
dpkg -i /cdrom/path-to/openssh-###.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be bothered to mess with your installation disk then just get it from the OpenSSH site: http://www.openssh.com/portable.html#http

Or, if you really want a *.deb package, get it on the launchpad site:

https://launchpad.net/openssh/main

Comment: What package should I use from launchpad? I can modify the installation so I guess that will be the best option

Comment: That's up to you. As long as you get the portable version you should be OK. I would get the latest myself, 6.6. You may run into dependency problems though, if that is the case then try 6.0 because that is the version which came with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen I also just noticed that the original link was actually to the source package. I've updated with the binary package page.